# jsreport with phantom-pdf recipe: how / where to set basic settings like format, margin, orientation...?

Tags: jsreport

I'm using jsreport (through npm) to render pdf from HTML using phantom-pdf recipe.

Rendering is started via an HTTPS call:

**https://127.0.0.1/api/report**

...and the post data is a string like this one:

```
{ 
"template": {
    "content": /*...my HTML content template to render...*/,
    "recipe": "phantom-pdf",
    "engine": "handlebars" 
    },
"data": /*json string with data to pass to the template*/
}
```

I know there are basic settings for phantom-pdf (margin, format, width, height, orientation, printDelay, waitForJS), but I didn't understand where to put them:
- in the HTML template?
- in the dev.conig.json file of jsreport?
- in a separate file?

...and how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send these settings as part of the API request body, inside `template.phantom` property.

```
{ 
  "template": {
    "content": /*...my HTML content template to render...*/,
    "recipe": "phantom-pdf",
    "engine": "handlebars",
    "phantom": { "margin": "5cm" }
  },
  "data": { "foo": "Hello" }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to store those settings with the template, how could I do?

Comment: I don't get the question. You simply press save button in jsreport studio and those settings are stored.

Comment: That's because I can't use jsreport studio. I have to manually edit the template file. Thanks

Comment: I can imagine some production rules prevents you from using the studio. However you can still create the template on your local and check how the format looks like.